# setting innerHTML - image not showing up but alt is

Tags: html, ajax, image, innerhtml

i have a page where i pull some html from an ajax request and then insert it into a div. the html is getting into the div correctly except that the image isn't showing up, but the alt text for it is. here is the html:

`<div class='fltright'><img src='images/esl.jpg' alt="English as a Second Language"/></div><!-- end fltright --><p><span class='large'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span> consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tempor semper tortor. </p>`

is there any reason that the image would not show while the alt text would?

**AJAX CODE:**

```
function getData(fileName){
    fileLoc = encodeURI("assets/"+fileName+".html")
    //alert(fileLoc);
    request.onreadystatechange = processData;
    request.open("GET",fileLoc, false);
    request.send();
    //alert(request.readyState);
    //alert(response);
    //alert(request.status);
}
function processData(){
    if (request.readyState==4){
        if (request.status==200){
            try{
                response = request.responseText;
                document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerHTML = response;
            } catch(e){
                alert("Error: " +e.description);
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("An error has occured making the request");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we take a peek at the AJAX request code?

Comment: maybe the URL to the `esl.jpg` may want a leading `/`? `images/esl.jpg` will look for an images sub dir relative to the page you are viewing. Does right click "View Image" actually show the image?

Comment: @Drav i added the leading `/` and nothing changed. however when i right click "view image" i get a `forbidden: you do not have permission to access /images/esl.jpg` any idea why that might be? i'm not great with permissions.

Comment: make sure the /images folder and all files within it are accessible by Apache (or whatever server you're using).  Generally setting permissions to 755 should do the job.

Comment: +1 to Endophage it was a permissions issue, add your answer and i'll accept

Comment: heh and a +1 from me on asking to see if you could _actually_ view the image ;) (given either the location of the file either didnt exist, or it was a permissions issue.. hence asking!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check that the image is actually viewable in these senarios. A good way to check that is to right click and "View Image...". that will then ask your browser to specifically just request that image.

If you get `Not Found` the requested image images/esl.jpg was not found on this server, then your url is incorrect.

If you get `Forbidden` You don't have permission to access images/esl.jpg on this server. Then it is a permissions issue. As Endophage said you will then want to set the correct file and directory permissions for the Apache process to be able to view that image.

Answer (score 0):

Often when using AJAX you forget where your images are in relation to where the document is. Try referencing the image from the root location, like this..

../images/esl.jpg

Comment: i thought of that and tried it (doesn't work) before i posted, thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the image is actually in assets/images/esl.jpg, not images/esl.jpg

Consider the difference between where your page sits and the page you're scraping sits...